# Sass variables and css styles in main.css

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

Actually I want to know something specific about sass, because I have no knowledge about sass. The question is. Do I have to link the scss file with a different css file where I am working or where I´m writing my styles and add it as another css source.

I ask this silly question, because I have already tried in a silly way to use the sass variables given on Bootstrap 5.3.2, but I failed, because I linked the sass file to my main.css and when I compiled the sass file my main.css file was overwritten and I have no idea why did it happen. So I want to know if theres a way to have css own styles mixed with sass variables. Excuse me if I do not have the profficiency nedded to ask here. Thank you and good day.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install Live Sass Compiler
First, launch Visual Studio Code. Once it's loaded, go to the side panel on the left and select the extensions tab.

1
Extensions tab in VS Code
In the search bar, search for "Live Sass Compiler" and install it. This extension helps us to compile the Sass files — .scss (or .sass) – into .css files.

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwMNz.png)

Step 2: Set the Save Location
Now change the file path so that Sass gets compiled into the styles folder.

To do this, you will make changes to the settings.json file.

In VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings. Now search for live sass compile to change the global settings.

Click on Edit settings.json.

Now, on the first few lines, where you see this code:

```
{
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "/"
    }
  ],

Change "savePath": "/" to "savePath": "/styles", so it now looks like this:

{
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName":".css",
      "savePath":"/styles",
    },

// You can also use this minified extension for production, as it reduces the file size



 {
      "format": "compressed",
      "extensionName":".min.css",
      "savePath":"/styles",
    }
  ],
```

Step 3: Compile Sass
Now, after saving the settings, go back to the Sass file, and click on the button that says "Watch Sass" at the very bottom of the window.

[how to turn on sass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RojTq.png)

Click on "Watch Sass"
After you click the button, two files get created: .css and a .css.map in the styles folder.

You should not, however, change any of them. Because it already helps you compile the Sass into CSS every time you save new stylings.

Step 4: Link the CSS file
Then, link the CSS file in your index.html. In our case:

Now run the file in your browser.

Comment: Ok I see, I understand the point, but I do not understand if I need another css file where to use the sass variables. I am using bootstrap 5.3, lite-server and the recommended sass compiler on the bootstrap documentation, I am not sure but I guess is dart sass or something like that, the point is that I tried to use the sass variables given for certain components, but when I put the compiler to watch the scss file for changes my main.css changed for the sass variables and I have no idea if I have to use one css file for css variables and another one for sass variables.